# Can encryption and Digital signatures produce exactly one file?

Tags: java, cryptography, public-key-encryption

I am trying to encrypt a file in Java using AES and then Digitally sign it and store it in a database, so that I can verify the signature and then decrypt it when I fetch that file. I have gone through Oracle's tutorial on digital signature but they create 3 files in the end, namely : Data, Signature & Public key. I am looking for a solution where I only get one file. Does any such kind of solution exist? I am new to cryptography so couldn't gather much information  about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your situation but you would only need a public key signature if **all** of the following things are true.  You want to:

1. run multiple versions of your AES encryption engine in different places
2. then need to be able to verify which server encrypted which files
3. while protecting against a man in the middle attack during this check

This is quite a rare scenario and I would suggest that you dont really need a public key signature.

Normally you would simply append a [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) "signature" to authenticate the file.  I am calling it a signature because it is a kind of signature in the sense that it uses the symmetric AES encryption/decryption key and the encrypted file contents to generate the code.  This will protect the integrity of the file from modification by people that dont know the encryption/decryption key.

If you are encrypting files using AES, I suggest using this free [open source file format](https://www.aescrypt.com/aes_file_format.html).  There is a [JAVA library available](https://www.aescrypt.com/download/) on the download page.

Answer (score 2):

That is of course possible. If you just concatenate the results (possibly proceded by a length indicator to keep them appart) then you would already have synthesized such a single blob, which can be stored in a file.

That would of course not be a very well described stucture. In cryptography there are already structures defined that do this. Outside the many structures defined for libraries such as RNCrypt there are two well known container formats: CMS and PGP. CMS or Cryptographic Message Syntax was described for SMIME originally and has evolved from the PKCS#7 standard by RSA. OpenPGP is used by applications such as PGP and GPG.

For Java both PGP and CMS functionality is provided by the Bouncy Castle libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: you can simply concatenate the resulting files into one (using separators so you can split them again).
Or you can put them all together into a zip file and extract them before processing.

oops missed the database part: there you can store the info either as ascii encoded varchar or directly read the resulting files into BLOBs